# Get row number of the first occurrence of 1 in each column

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, iteration

I have a matrix that is:

```
matrix = [1, 0, 0;  
          0, 1, 1;
          0, 0, 1];
```

I want to iterate through the matrix column by column and get the row number of the first `1` occurred in that column. So, the result is supposed to be:

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

What I have idea so far is:

```
for i = matrix
    if i == 1
       %store the row No. to an array.
    end
end
```

Comment: If you have just zeros and ones in your matrix then `[~,r]= max(A)` will do the job. Otherwise `[~,r]=max(A==1)` Also check the linked duplicate for more ideas.

Comment: I'd use `[~,Indices] = max(matrix,[],2)` to ensure that the furthest left index is selected.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 The OP is interested in the row subscript of first occurrence of 1 in each column i.e. `[1,2,2]`. Whereas `max(matrix,[],2)` returns the column subscript of first occurrence of 1 in each row.i.e. `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @Sandar Usama My bad, I was mistaken. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 @SardarUsama, you can then just transpose the matrix. `[~,Indices] = max(matrix', [], 2)` returns exactly `[1, 2, 2]`.

Comment: @MatteoV 1. That's a complex conjugate transpose; not transpose 2. This is an overkill. No need of taking complex conjugate transpose when you can just directly use max

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
row = zeros(size(matrix,2),1);
for column = 1:size(matrix,2)
    row(column) = find(matrix(:,column),1);
end
```

there might be a better way without the loop..